# Build method isn't immedietly called in flutter due to global variabes

Tags: variables, flutter, dart, global

I am writing an app for hotel registration. There are **multiple fillup forms** to get all relevant information/data. But I have kept each fillup form in different class. There are **next and back** buttons at the bottom of screen. I have created several global variables so that they can be accessed throughout the project. 
For screen changes on next button taps,  I have created a list of form screens.

```dart
List<Widget> formScreens = [personal_info,login_creds, bank_details,hotel_configs]
```

So when I Tap **Next** button there is a global variable (index) which changes value by +1 to iterate over formScreens.

```dart
setState(){
    globals.index-=-1;
}
```

I have created these naviagators (next and back  buttons) in a different class. They also work fine.

But When I tap on the Next button, Build method, which controlls all the different components and creates a body, isn't called immediatly, thus not updating screen to the next screen. But when I tap on any of the formFields, build method is invoked and the screen changes to next fillup form.

[This is on my first screen, so there is no back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSKC5.jpg)

I have segregated each component because it was fairly large amount of code to be kept in a single class.

**Or** is there any other way that I can use segregated components and access them throughout the project?

Comment: instead of creating a list of widgets for multiple pages, use [PageView](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded). It will save time for you in building such  UI templates.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without code, never seen this kind of behavior in flutter. It would help if you can post the code of the widget where you are calling setState